# Decoding a telephone number that was masked with letters from the respective keys with APL

Tags: apl

Legend says phones used to have keys<sup>[citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)</sup> and in those times, a person could "encode" a phone number by creating a word from the letters in the keys with the given numbers.

Below is the usual layout of the keys (that matter for my question) of a phone:

```
     | abc | def |
  1  |  2  |  3  |
------------------
 ghi | jkl | mno |
  4  |  5  |  6  |
------------------
pqrs | tuv | wxyz|
  7  |  8  |  9  |
------------------
```

I have to write a function that, given a vector of characters with uppercase letters/digits, recovers the original phone number.

For example,

```
'HELLO' -> 4 3 5 5 6
'IAMYY4U' -> 4 2 6 9 9 4 8
'' -> ⍬
```

This is the code I have written:

```
Telephone ← {
  ⍝ Monadic function taking an uppercase string as input.
  ⍝ Decodes the number expressed with uppercase letters,
  ⍝ e.g. '1ABCZ' gives '12229'

  ⍝ Split letters and digits according to their keys (each digit goes to itself)
  keyStarts ← 'ADGJMPTW'
  splits ← ⎕D, keyStarts
  classes ← (1 -⍨ ⍳10), 1 + ⍳8

  classes[splits ⍸ ⍵]
}
```

I am particularly interested in a better way to create the `classes` variable, that looks like this `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and this ordering depends obviously on the order of `splits`.

This comes from [a problem from an APL competition](https://www.dyalogaplcompetition.com/?goto=P16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am particularly interested in a better way to create the `classes` variable, [...] this ordering depends obviously on the order of `splits`.

Because ASCII codes of `A..Z` come later than those of `0..9`, we can't shorten the `classes` array itself. Instead, we can *lengthen* it, so that `classes` becomes simply two copies of `0..9`. You can create unused intervals by copying the boundary item that comes *after* them:

```
    'BBB' ⍸ 'ABCD'
0 3 3 3
```

Incorporating it in `Telephone`:

```
  splits ← ⎕D, 'AAADGJMPTW'
  classes ← ,⍨ 1 -⍨ ⍳10
```

---

**Nitpicking:** When I need to subtract 1 from an expression, I use `¯1+expr` instead of `1-⍨expr` because the former reads better to me. This is a personal choice though. Or, if the "subtract 1" appears only for generating `0..n-1` instead of `1..n` with `⍳`, consider using `⎕IO←0`.

---

Now, `splits` is creating the interval indices `0..20`, and except the first 0, each index is mapped to `0..9,0..9`.

```
interval index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
class         : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Do you see the pattern? If you discard the unused interval and take modulo 10, you get the right class! Then you can entirely discard the variable `classes` and extra indexing:

```
Telephone ← {
  splits ← 1↓ ⎕D, 'AAADGJMPTW'
  10| splits ⍸ ⍵
}
```

Comment: I like your "nitpicking" here about the `¯1 + ...`. I have adopted it in my code already. Also, really nice simplification of the code with the extended `splits`, thanks!